# IndexBound in MongoDB Explain()

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called test

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62445018d295a5214160af2c"), "key" : 20 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6244501cd295a5214160af2d"), "key" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62445021d295a5214160af2e"), "key" : 40 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62445026d295a5214160af2f"), "key" : 50 }
```

This command   `db.test.explain("executionStats").find( { $or: [{key:{$gt:20}}, {key:{$lt:50} } ]})` produced a result containing

```
"indexBounds" : {
                   "key" : [
                             "[-1.#INF, 1.#INF]"
                            ]
                                        }
```

Please what is the meaning of `[-1.#INF, 1.#INF]` and why  `[-1.#INF, 1.#INF]`

Secondly,

Here is users collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62444bcfd295a5214160af28"), "LastName" : "HARRIS" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62444bd8d295a5214160af29"), "LastName" : "HARRISON" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62444be7d295a5214160af2a"), "LastName" : "HARRI" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62444c63d295a5214160af2b"), "LastName" : "HARRI" }
```

...

```
 `db.users.explain("executionStats").find({LastName:{$regex:/^HARRIS(.*)/}})`
```

produced a result containing

```
"indexBounds" : { "LastName" : [
                                                "[\"HARRIS\", \"HARRIT\")",
                                                "[/^HARRIS(.*)/, /^HARRIS(.*)/]"
                                        ]
                                }
```

Please I need an explanation the value of indexBounds above

Comment: What is the purpose of the query filter `{ $or: [ {key: { $gt: 20 } }, { key: { $lt: 50 } } ] }` ?

Comment: I want to run a query to get a result where key is greater than 20 or less than 50